# django-forms-builder. How do I update a form?

Tags: python, django

I am using `django-forms-builder` in my project and there is just one thing i cant get my head around. How do i set up an update form to edit a filled out form?

Here is my attempt at making an update form for `django-forms-builder`

urls.py

```
url('forms/update/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', FormUpdateView.as_view(),
                                 name='form-update'),
```

views.py

```
class FormUpdateView(UpdateView):
    model = FieldEntry
    template_name = 'form/update_form.html'
    form_class = FormForForm
    success_url = '/assessments/all/'
```

update-form.py

```
{% render_built_form id=form_instance.id %}
```

Comment: you need to find a way to pass an instance of the form model into your view as `form_instance`

Comment: you're probably best sub-classing or modifying the existing `FormDetail` view that comes with django-forms-builder https://github.com/stephenmcd/django-forms-builder/blob/master/forms_builder/forms/views.py

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I haven't used this software yet but it could fill a spot in my arsenal so I took a stab at it.  I'm not using CBV because I'm still just poking around.  This is the get part only, I can expand on how to handle the post part (and preferably do it with CBV) on the weekend.  It's relatively straightforward to implement post with view functions (`if request.METHOD == "POST":#update the row`).  The render is of course just plain raw HTML but forms_builder doesn't offer any styling input.  You probably want to tack the user onto the FormEntry, I don't have a good idea about authorization yet.  I'll give it some thought and amend the answer.

views.py

```
from forms_builder.forms.models import Form

def get_form(request, slug, pk):
    form_obj = Form.objects.get(slug=slug)
    form_instance = form_obj.entries.get(pk=pk)
    form = FormForForm(form=form_obj, instance=form_instance, context=request)
    return render_to_response('update_form.html', {'form':form_instance.form, 'request':request})
```

templates/update_form.html

```
{{ form.as_p }}
```